# User Experience site unreadable

Tags: bug, support, status-norepro

Firefox version 29.0 Ubuntu 14.04 : when I access the site I see this:

[image: user experience]

Everything looks OK in Chrome. And since Firefox is my primary browser I would like to access the site from Firefox (because FF gives me better user experience of browsing the web *pun intended*)

Other sites, like StackOverflow are displayed OK.

Before this happened, I installed regular Ubuntu updates and rebooted my PC

What should I do?

Comment: You state "I just installed some updates from the Ubuntu and restarted" so why would you assume that a random site on the internet would just "break"? It's more likely to be one of the updates that caused this.

Comment: I know. But still - is there something I could check? Like helvetica font installation? (although I dont know how exactly)

Comment: I'd check which updates you actually installed and see if any of them messed with the fonts on the system. As Martin said on the old MSE question - "The difference between UX and Meta.SE is that UX has 'Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif, Meta uses 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif for the font definition. I'd go see about my Arial font installation."

Comment: on it now: http://askubuntu.com/questions/465661/how-to-see-what-was-updated-in-last-update

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it only affected one user at one point in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved** But do not ask me how. Did several reboots of PC and browser ... and *It healed itself magically*

I **hate** these kind of bugs...